# Distribution of data in buckets - Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with two columns `BRANCH` and `ACTIVITIES`, where `BRANCH` is a unique id of location and `ACTIVITIES` are number of records belong to respective `BRANCH`. These records to be distributed in 5 buckets in a way that all buckets should contain almost equal number of records. (no matter if difference is +/-1000)

The challenge is if one branch is selected in a bucket then all activities of same branch will also be selected in same bucket, in other words, number of activities belong to one `BRANCH` cannot be split. Lets take a very simple example so that I can explain what I am trying to achieve

```
Total Branches=10
Total Number of activities (records) = 55,000
Average (total activities/total buckets) = 11,000
```

Sample Data

[image]

After Distribution

[image]

All buckets contain 11,000 records but things are not such straight forward when we look into real data [real data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=59b9ae0609faee931b85f1e0b6fffd7d)

All Oracle query masters are requested to please look into this. Your expert opinion will highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is a bin-packing problem and a "perfect" solution requires -- essentially -- searching through all possible assignments of buckets and then choosing the "best" one.  And such an approach is not really suitable for SQL.

For a "good-enough" solution, though, something like a round-robin approach often works well.  Simply enumerate the branches from biggest to smallest and assign them to buckets:

```
select a.branch,
       1 + mod(seqnum, 5) as bucket
from (select a.branch, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (order by count(*)) desc as seqnum
      from activities a
      group by a.branch
     ) a;
```

Because of the ordering, this is going to generally create buckets of different sizes.  So, a slight variation assigns the buckets as 1-2-3-4-5-5-4-3-2-1:

```
select a.branch,
       (case when mod(seqnum, 10) in (0, 9) then 1
             when mod(seqnum, 10) in (1, 8) then 2
             when mod(seqnum, 10) in (2, 7) then 3
             when mod(seqnum, 10) in (3, 6) then 4
             when mod(seqnum, 10) in (4, 5) then 5
        end) as bucket
from (select a.branch, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (order by count(*)) desc as seqnum
      from activities a
      group by a.branch
     ) a;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I executed query on real_data (link given in my question) and found the result which is acceptable to some extent. Buckets contain records like: (1) 17,473 (2)15,797 (3) 21,685 (4) 15,427 (5) 13,811. Can you please explain in (0,9) , in (1,8) and so on?

Comment: @ATTA . . . I thought that I did in the sentence above it.

Comment: Yes you are right, thanks for solution with explanation. Just thinking a loud, what if we take average which is in this case 16,839 and make it threshold and start counting/accumulating No. of records from top to bottom after ordering the column and keep it continuing until it reaches/crosses threshold and then assign all counted branches to bucket 1 and then start counting/accumulating from next record till threshold and assign to Bucket 2. Looking for your expert opinion on this.

Comment: @ATTA . . . That is an alternative method, but it requires an iterative solution and would be much slower.  In addition, it is not optimal.  For more optimal results, you can accumulate buckets by the largest amounts up to -- but not over the average.  Then distribute the smallest values to get them closer to the average.  Your question, though, suggests that an approximation is okay, which is why I suggest this approach (and it works well unless you have a small number of outlier values).

Comment: the given solution is fine as long as we consider the data in given example but it can't tackle data fluctuation, as when i applied it on other data set in which one branch has >47K records, the above query assigned this branch to bucket one but it kept continuing adding other branches in the same bucket and ultimately bucket 1 became very large than others. However, thanks for your solution, time and explanation. Keep up you good work :)

Comment: I managed it through program which works excellent as per requirement. However, in the given context of the question, you solution works as well. So I am marking it as an acceptable answer. Thanks for your time. Keep up your good work.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try below query. I added some stats columns in this inline view stats_cols_added_tab before I applied dense_rank analytic function to that inline view. Finally I used NTILE analytic function to get five groups.

```sql
with sample_data (branch, activities) as (
select 1, 1000 from dual union all
select 2, 2000 from dual union all
select 3, 3000 from dual union all
select 4, 4000 from dual union all
select 5, 5000 from dual union all
select 6, 6000 from dual union all
select 7, 7000 from dual union all
select 8, 8000 from dual union all
select 9, 9000 from dual union all
select 10, 10000 from dual
)
,
stats_cols_added_tab as (
    select s.*
    , count(*)over() total_branches
    , sum(activities)over() total_number_of_activities
    , avg(activities)over() * 2 Average
    , case when row_number()over(order by s.branch) <= count(*)over() / 2 then 1 else 2 end grp
from sample_data s
)
SELECT BRANCH, ACTIVITIES, NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY ranked_grp,  BRANCH) AS bucket  
FROM (
        select BRANCH, ACTIVITIES
            , dense_rank()over(
                PARTITION BY grp 
                    order by decode(grp, 1, activities, -1 * activities)
                    ) ranked_grp
        from stats_cols_added_tab t 
    ) t
order by ranked_grp, BRANCH
;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If you execute this query or "real data" then you will get 97 buckets whilst I need 5 only.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Now I made an update to my answer now to put rows into five different groups.